# Random number generator with varies conditions. 3 digits

Tags: random

Hi i am working on a random number generator which i faced a road block. I have done my program but i'm quite lost on how to do a loop for the C++ program to keep on looping. following below is the conditions for program:

1. The program prompts the user to enter a number.
2. This number determines the number of times the loop will repeat. The number ranges from 0 to 100. Validate this range.
3. The program uses a random number to generate a number from 0 to 9999 and then
   checks if the generated number contains the digit 1, digit 2 or digit 3.

Please advise on how do i require to do a switch or while loop for point 3.
your inputs is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What language.?

Comment: C++ bro.. sorry for now stating in the program earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to check would be to use the mod operation and division to extract every digit.

A loop would be something like

```
int randInt = randomFunction();
while(randInt > 0){
  //Get Last Digit
  int lastDigit = randInt % 10;

  switch(lastDigit){
    case 1:
    // do something
    break;
    case 2:
    // do something
    break;
    case 3:
    // do something
    break;
  }

  /* 
   Divide the number by 10 to remove the last digit.
   Integers will automatically truncate remainders.
   i.e int a = 21/10, a will = 2 
  */
  randInt /= 10;

}
```